# How Do I Select all Objects via a Relationship Model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Given the Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

class Thingie(models.Model):
    children = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False) 

class Relation(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    thingie = models.ForeignKey(Thingie)
```

How would one return a QuerySet containing all Profile instances related to a given Thingie?  That is, every Profile that has a foreign key pointing to it from a Relation and to the given thingie.

I know all about select_related(), and how I could use it to do this by iterating but i find iterating irritating (badoop bah!).  Also, values_list() has been looked at, but it doesn't quite do the right thing.

Please help!  Thanks!

Comment: Huh? What's the relationship between Profile and Relation? What's the relationship between Relation and Thingie? What are GrooveUser and Media? Please try to distill your question to its simplest meaningful form.

Comment: My bad, I accidentally left in some real code instead of simplified snippet/example code.  Fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you definitely need it to be a queryset? If you only need it to be an iterable, a simple expression for your purposes is:

```
profiles = [r.profile for r in thingie.relation_set.all()]
```

I'm not sure if a list comprehension counts as irritating iterating, but to me this is a perfectly intuitive, pythonic approach. Of course if you need it to be a queryset, you're going to do something messier with two queries, eg:

```
relation_values = thingie.relation_set.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(relation__in=relation_values)
```

See the "[in](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)" documentation for more. I prefer the first approach, if you don't need a queryset. Oh and if you only want distinct profiles you can just take `set(profiles)` in the first approach or use the [`distinct()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) queryset method in the second approach.

Comment: List comprehension definitely works well, but the OP was complaining about iterating (which is basically what a list comprehension does)...

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the Django doc on [Making queries](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)?  It has a simple example of achieving what you want, more specifically [Lookups that span relationships](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).  Make sure you refer the code snippets in the latter link to the model code at the beginning of the page.

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation end-to-end quite a few times.  However, I seem only to be able to get comparison information by spanning relationships(IE: find me all Thingies where thingie.profile.user = X), not actual instances themselves (IE: Find me all relation.profiles where relation.thingie = y).

Answer (score 0):

Without defining a direct relationship between Profile and Thingie, you can't.

The best way would be to add a ManyToMany to Thingie that points to Profile and use the `through` argument ([django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)) on the ManyToMany to specify your Relation model/table.

That way you can do a direct filter operation on Thingie to get your profiles and still store your intermediate Relation data.

Comment: I may end up using this because it is more in line with Django best practices, but I felt the second part of the above answer was more accurate for this question. Thanks!